# org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

hi when I calling an jsp page, then I'm facing  org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including jsp path in spring mvc. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Add the code where you try to give path to the JSP.

Comment: i already added code but i found same error. It's work fine on local server but not on aws.